# Why does this Ajax request not seem to pass the JS variable through to PHP?

Tags: javascript, php, ajax

I'm currently struggling to figure out how to pass variables from JS to PHP using Ajax. I have tried using the following Ajax code

```
xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();

function myFunction() {
    xhr.open("GET", "welcome.php");
    xhr.send("your_name=john&your_age=40");

    xhr.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if(xhr.readyState === 4) {
            document.getElementById("output").innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
        }

    }
}
```

Combined with a PHP script called welcome.php which looks as follows:

```
$user = $_GET['your_name'];
var_dump($user);
```

For some reason, however, this outputs 'NULL' and I can't work out why.

I've also tried including `echo $user;` in file welcome.php, but this doesn't return anything.

Anyone know why this is happening?

Comment: how about json_encode?

Comment: Try `json_encode($user)` instead.

Comment: I'm not really familiar with that function, but changing var_dump($user); to json_encode($user); still doesn't give an output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you are using method GET, as stated in [.send documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/send)

> If the request method is GET or HEAD, the argument is ignored and request body is set to null.

What you want to do is

```
xhr.open("GET", "welcome.php?your_name=john&your_age=40");
```